# How to conditionally forward messages between two bridged MQTT broker?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, mosquitto, bridge, broker

I have a MQTT Broker (mosquitto) located at site A and another broker (mosquitto  or RabbitMQ) at cloud. In order for data to be forwarded to cloud, I plan to bridged them and TLS-ed for data security.

1. At site A, software are communicate internally through MQTT and I DO NOT wish sensitive data be send to the cloud. (e.g: topic with "user/password")
2. Non-sensitive information such as "user/age", "user/gender" is send to cloud for statistical analysis.

How to configure broker at site A to bridged and conditionally only forward certain topic/message to the cloud broker (while maintaining internal messaging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no negative matching or programmatic matching in mosquitto  so you have 2 options:

1. Totally separate the topic tree for the sensitive data and use a wildcard bridge configuration to send all the non sensitive data to the remote broker

   - user/age
   - user/gender
   - security/password

     ```
     connection cloud
     address cloud.broker.foo
     topic user/# out
     ```
2. Add individual topic bridge configurations for each topic you wish to bridge.

   ```
   connection cloud
   address cloud.broker.foo
   topic user/age out
   topic user/gender out
   ```